# SetEntryInHash vs. SetEntryInHashIfNotExists

Tags: c#, redis, servicestack

I've read in a couple places that Redis is idempotent, so a repeated call to `SetEntryInHash()` will have no effect, right?

Is there any good case for using `SetEntryInHashIfNotExists()`?  Can this give quicker results than just blindly calling `SetEntryInHash()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Idempotent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence) means you can replay the same action multiple times and it will have the same side-effect. Only idempotent operations like [SADD](http://redis.io/commands/sadd) are idempotent, i.e. after calling that 1 or more than 1 times you will end up with the same result, i.e. a single item in the set.

Adding to a redis list, e.g. [LINSERT](http://redis.io/commands/linsert) is by contrast not idempotent as every new item adds a new item to the redis list.

If you want to know how operations in [ServiceStack's Redis Client](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis) are implemented, just inspect the source code. [SetEntryInHash and SetEntryInHashIfNotExists are here](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Redis/RedisClient_Hash.cs#L51-59). They both call [HSET](http://redis.io/commands/HSET) and [HSETNX](http://redis.io/commands/HSETNX) respectively. Refer to the documentation in redis to learn about the behavior of each operation.

Comment: Couldn't help but notice you answered his question merely 20 minutes later, and still didn't get the "answer" nod.  Go figure.

Answer (score 2):

@mythz is right, with the source code at hand, quick to find the real answer, not to mention also including links to the redis documentation.  I was curious about the difference myself, and thought I would post the clarification here for others.

**HSETNX** : Sets field in the hash stored at key to value, ***only if field does not yet exist***. If key does not exist, a new key holding a hash is created. If field already exists, this operation ***has no effect***.

**HSET** : Sets field in the hash stored at key to value. If key does not exist, a new key holding a hash is created. If field already exists in the hash, ***it is overwritten***.